# ViewPager/ScrollView with multiple view/fragments of different sizes

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I am looking for an viewpager or scrollview implementation or guidance on how to construct one that mimics that of the Circa News application, shown below.

The ViewPager or ScrollView implementation needs to be able to handle views or fragments(either, not or) of different sizes. Allowing for any size, smaller than full screen and larger also. The focus would be on the top most(top aligned) view/fragment. The scrollbar indicator on the right side is not a requirement.

[image: Circa News vertical viewpager]

So far i've found Mark Murphy's analysis on the basic problem, but all of the results don't fit the situation exactly. [Link](http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/08/20/multiple-view-viewpager-options.html)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding this answer while looking for something else, but it partly works for the question i posed with a few caveats.

[Parchment](https://github.com/EmirWeb/parchment) is a "Horizontal/Vertical ListView, GridView, ViewPager, and GridPatternView". The key part is the ViewPager, but bad part is its not its a listview and does not support fragments as a normal ViewPager would. But you can achieve the same result.

You use Parchment like any other ListView, the key is in the configuration(which i believe can only be done via xml).

> ```
> <mobi.parchment.widget.adapterview.listview.ListView
>    android:id="@+id/verticalviewpager"
>    android:layout_width="match_parent"
>    android:layout_height="match_parent"
>    parchment:orientation="vertical"
>    parchment:isViewPager="true"
>    parchment:snapToPosition="true"
>    parchment:snapPosition="start" />
> ```

The key is "isViewPager", "snapToPosition" and "snapPosition". This enables the list act like a ViewPager. Only difference is the views are from an Adapter's getView() instead of a fragment.